# Upgraded to .net core 2.1 and now I can't serialize a claim

Tags: .net-core, azure-service-fabric

I currently send claims (System.Security.Claims.Claim type) between two Azure micro-services. When I was on .net Core 2.0 this worked fine. The service fabric comms layer serialised and deserialised as expected. When I upgrade to .net core 2.1 I now get the error:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: 'Type 'System.Security.Claims.Claim' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. Alternatively, you can ensure that the type is public and has a parameterless constructor - all public members of the type will then be serialized, and no attributes will be required.'

Comment: I don't know what the issue was, but I've dropped use of the Claim type alltogether and I am now using my own UserClaim type instead. Probably cleaner that way anyway.

Comment: Also had other serialisation issues here, if others are interested. I had service interfaces with a mix of IEnumerable<XXX> and List<XXX> the serialiser complained about two different types having the same data contract name. To fix this I had to change all IEnumerble responses types and parameters to List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you've answered this by having a separate claim type. Not sure what changed on the .NET claim type, but it must have. https://fuget.org/packages/System.Security.Claims/4.3.0/lib/netstandard1.3/diff/4.0.1/ doesn't immediately show anything, may have to really diassemble things to see the difference.

You can also get around this by having a custom serializer that you can control and which is more permissive. This works particularly well with your own types since you can explicitly control the process.

More info on that is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-reliable-collections-serialization#custom-serialization